Computing surface Laplacian/Laplace Beltrami in R using Delaunay triangulation
I have been researching methods to compute the Laplacian/Laplace-Beltrami operator, but I've found that R lacks built functions for these purposes. There is actually a package that allows for normalization of such operator ::matrixLaplacian.
I am interested in deriving the Laplace-Beltrami operator using a discrete approach, preferably Delaunay triangulation.
The main steps are: 1) Create a mesh using the Delaunay triangulation 2) Compute the area matrix and cotangent weight matrix (which is the Laplace-Beltrami discrete operator). To do it so, the cotangent is used.
I am also open to receive any other approaches.
#Just for starters

vertices <-t(matrix(runif(30), ncol = 10))
colnames(vertices) <- c("x", "y", "z")
tri_mesh <- geometry::delaunayn(vertices) #creating a mesh?

#Possible solution using igraph ? (not sure this might be correct)
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(tri_mesh, directed = FALSE, vertices = 1:10)
L <- laplacian_matrix(g,normalized = T, weights = NA)

1  0  .          .         .  .         .  .          .         .  .        
2  .  1.0000000 -0.1543033 . -0.1428571 . -0.4364358 -0.2390457 . -0.3779645
3  . -0.1543033  1.0000000 . -0.1543033 .  .         -0.5163978 .  .        
4  .  .          .         0  .         .  .          .         .  .        
5  . -0.1428571 -0.1543033 .  1.0000000 . -0.2182179 -0.4780914 .  .        
6  .  .          .         .  .         0  .          .         .  .        
7  . -0.4364358  .         . -0.2182179 .  1.0000000  .         .  .        
8  . -0.2390457 -0.5163978 . -0.4780914 .  .          1.0000000 .  .        
9  .  .          .         .  .         .  .          .         0  .        
10 . -0.3779645  .         .  .         .  .          .         .  1.0000000


Well, what do your g and L look like?  As it stands we don't know what's expected.

Not sure the approach is the correct. See http://mobile.rodolphe-vaillant.fr/entry/101/definition-laplacian-matrix-for-triangle-meshes. I added a correction and the output, but not sure is the correct Laplacian @Carl Witthoft.

Looking more carefully (thanks, Google!),  I see the package Rdimtools says it uses the Laplace-Beltrami operator.  This might be a good tool for you, or for you to compare your code with.

LMGTFY as is sometimes said.

@Chris  I decided to be nice for once :-)

What and how to search are still elusive, and I use cgwtools::seqle nearly weekly.
